# Adding a reference to C# project it's immediately invalid

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to add a reference to a C# class library project.  It's immediately shown as invalid in Solution Explorer.  The project is targeting .NET framework 4.5.

In order to add the reference, I'm right clicking on References -> Add Reference -> Then picking Microsoft.CSharp Version 4.0.0.0 from the Framework Assemblies.

After I've added the reference if I look at the properties on the Microsoft.CSharp Assembly that I've added it shows as Version 0.0.0.0  Any idea what's wrong?

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.

Here's what the references look like in the csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.Core" />
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.WebRequest" />
<Reference Include="System.Web" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
<Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
<Reference Include="System.Data" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
```

Comment: Did you check: http://www.solvusoft.com/en/files/missing-not-found-error/dll/windows/flavor-retail/microsoft-silverlight/microsoft-csharp-dll/

Comment: The link you posted looks decidedly sketchy.

Comment: Did you try to download Microsoft.CSharp.dll online and add it as a reference?

Comment: The same assembly is working just fine in other projects.

Comment: So, does this project has a web.config (or something similar)? If yes, it might be related to web,config. Do you have something similar to these lines in the web.config? <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
<providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0" />

Comment: I have   <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" /> It's the same in the project that's working though.

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried turning it off and then on again?  Clean/rebuild/etc?

Comment: OK. What about to version of c# language. Can u please go to Project Properties -> Build -> Advanced and check c# versions?

Comment: also when you hover over the `Microsoft.CSharp` assembly in the add references dialogue, are you getting the path you would expect?

Comment: It looks normal to me                                                                                Name: Microsoft.CSharp
Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5
\Microsoft,CSharp.dll
Version: 4.0.0.0
File Version: 4.030319.18020

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will be helpful to anyone else in the future, but I fixed these issues by fixing some other reference issues.

I had created this C# class library project using some proprietary scaffolding written by the company that I work for.  The scaffolding is somewhat out of date and created some reference problems with some company-supplied references as well.  At any rate, fixing these other references seem to fix the System.xml, Microsoft.Csharp, etc. ones as well.